# Why is my mutator function not working correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

I am attempting to apply a pay raise function to a variable that is in a class but when I call the function it gives me an Attribute Error saying it does not exist in said class when I know it is there and I have written it in a similar manner I was taught. I have given two of the classes and the function call that is giving me the error.

I have attempted adding the missing attribute to the parameters of the main class that is being inherited from as well as calling it on different classes to see if it makes a difference.

Edited to remove code unnecessary to question.

```
class Employee:

    pay_raise = 1.04

    def __init__(self, name, eNumber, hDate):
        self.__name = name
        self.__number = eNumber
        self.__date = hDate

    def raise_pay(self):
        self.__payrate = self.__payrate * self.pay_raise

class ProductionWorker(Employee):


    def __init__(self, name, eNumber, hDate, sNumber, pay):

        Employee.__init__(self, name, eNumber, hDate)

        self.__shiftNumber = sNumber
        self.__payrate = pay

    def set_payrate(self, pay):
        self.__payrate = pay

    def get_payrate(self):
        return self.__payrate

#newEmp is object created of ProductionWorker class. Is in tester file in main function.
newEmp.raise_pay()
```

Expected to multiply self.__payrate by the pay_raise and further in a print statement show new pay rate. When run as it is currently I am given the output "AttributeError: 'ProductionWorker' object has no attribute '_Employee__payrate'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Name Mangling](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables) exists in order to make variables with names like `__payrate` harder to access outside of the class in which it was defined. Even subclasses of that class cannot easily access the variable.

It is more conventional to use only one underscore to denote a private attribute. Then name mangling will not apply, and your private attributes will be accessible in child classes. (They will also be accessible everywhere else, but naughty users will access them at their own risk with the understanding that things can go very wrong for them if you decide to change up the internals of your class.)

```
class Employee:

    pay_raise = 1.04

    def __init__(self, name, eNumber, hDate):
        self._name = name
        self._number = eNumber
        self._date = hDate

    def raise_pay(self):
        self._payrate = self._payrate * self.pay_raise

class ProductionWorker(Employee):


    def __init__(self, name, eNumber, hDate, sNumber, pay):

        Employee.__init__(self, name, eNumber, hDate)

        self._shiftNumber = sNumber
        self._payrate = pay

    def set_payrate(self, pay):
        self._payrate = pay

    def get_payrate(self):
        return self._payrate

newEmp = ProductionWorker("Fred", 1, 1, 1, 100)
newEmp.raise_pay()
print(newEmp.get_payrate())
```

Result:

```
104.0
```

---

Bonus style tips:

- If Employee's methods access `_payrate`, then you should initialize it in Employee's `__init__`, even if you have to give it a placeholder value.
- getters and setters are conventionally implemented using the `@property` decorator, which makes accessing the public values easier.

```
class Employee:

    pay_raise = 1.04

    def __init__(self, name, eNumber, hDate):
        self._name = name
        self._number = eNumber
        self._date = hDate

        self._payrate = 0

    @property
    def payrate(self):
        return self._payrate

    @payrate.setter
    def payrate(self, value):
        self._payrate = value

    def raise_pay(self):
        self.payrate *= self.pay_raise

class ProductionWorker(Employee):
    def __init__(self, name, eNumber, hDate, sNumber, pay):

        Employee.__init__(self, name, eNumber, hDate)

        self._shiftNumber = sNumber
        self.payrate = pay


newEmp = ProductionWorker("Fred", 1, 1, 1, 100)
newEmp.raise_pay()
print(newEmp.payrate)
```

Finally, you might be better off not using a getter or setter at all, if all they're going to do is get and set the private value without changing anything else. Just use a plain old attribute.

```
class Employee:

    pay_raise = 1.04

    def __init__(self, name, eNumber, hDate):
        self._name = name
        self._number = eNumber
        self._date = hDate

        self.payrate = 0

    def raise_pay(self):
        self.payrate *= self.pay_raise

class ProductionWorker(Employee):
    def __init__(self, name, eNumber, hDate, sNumber, pay):

        Employee.__init__(self, name, eNumber, hDate)

        self._shiftNumber = sNumber
        self.payrate = pay


newEmp = ProductionWorker("Fred", 1, 1, 1, 100)
newEmp.raise_pay()
print(newEmp.payrate)
```

Comment: The pay rate should be part of the `Employee` class, since `Employee.raise_pay` requires it. `ProductionWorker` can override it if necessary.

Comment: That is how I thought to do it but the way the assignment is written he wanted each class to have it's own individual pay rate attributes. Thanks for all the tips, going to implement some of them in my code.

Comment: How silly -- if every subclass of Employee has the same attribute, then of course that attribute should be defined in the base class and not individually in each subclass. Go ahead and do whatever gives you the best grade for the course, but keep in mind what the real best practice is :-)